# Need help looking for a question about the veracity of an anecdote (astronaut floating in middle spacecraft) and the video I think I've linked there

Tags: support, specific-question

I've spent about 10 minutes searching every way I know how for a question about a story/anecdote that an astronaut wrote about. It asked about a recounted story of the astronaut exiting a capsule and entering a space station, and getting help to achieve motionlessness wrt the environment.

The astronaut then wrote about doing various tests to see if they could locomote/propel themselves to the wall so they could grab something.

The question asked if the story was true and took place as described, or if they had used some literary license to make it sound more interesting.

*I think that* I left an answer or a comment which included a YouTube video of an exercise similar to this which took place in some spacecraft or space station that was not the ISS.

Does this sound familliar? Can someone help me find the question?

---

**update:** I think that the video I'd linked to there is a version of the video in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/51937/12102) or the one in [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45252/12102) but not sure if I'd used one of these or found a better quality version, so I'm looking for the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Found it!

linked in [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8073/can-you-swim-in-space#comment169842_8075) under *Can you swim in space?*

It is the deleted currently-deleted question [Just how “stranded in the middle of the room” did Dan Barry actually get?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51610/12102)

I'd edited the video (found in a [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/51610/just-how-stranded-in-the-middle-of-the-room-did-dan-barry-actually-get#comment169991_51610) back into the question (to try to stave off some of the drive-by down-voting), and it is indeed of higher quality (480p vs 240p for the other two):